# python beautifulsoup web scraping issue

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
page = requests.get("http://www.freejobalert.com/upsc-recruitment/16960/#Engg-Services2019")
c = page.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
data=soup.find_all("tr")
for r in data:
    td = r.find_all("td",{"style":"text-align: center;"})
    for d in td:
        link =d.find_all("a")
        for li in link:
            span = li.find_all("span",{"style":"color: #008000;"})
            for s in span:
                strong = s.find_all("strong")
                for st in strong:
                        dict['title'] = st.text
        for l in link:
            dict["link"] = l['href']
    print(dict)
```

It is giving

```
{'title': 'Syllabus', 'link': 'http://www.upsc.gov.in/'}
{'title': 'Syllabus', 'link': 'http://www.upsc.gov.in/'}
{'title': 'Syllabus', 'link': 'http://www.upsc.gov.in/'}
```

I am expecting:

```
{'title': 'Apply Online', 'link': 'https://upsconline.nic.in/mainmenu2.php'}
{'title': 'Notification', 'link': 'http://www.freejobalert.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/Notification-UPSC-Engg-Services-Prelims-Exam-2019.pdf'}
{'title': 'Official Website ', 'link': 'http://www.upsc.gov.in/'}
```

Here i want all "Important Links" means "Apply online","Notification","official website"
 and it's link for each table.
but it is giving me "Syllabus" in title instead with repeting links..

please have a look into this..

Comment: Avoid using python namespace such as `dict` as variable name. You're also not initializing the dict variable anywhere? You have 5 level of loops, of which 4 levels appear to share the 'dict' variable. Rethink your approach, why loop? Loop implies multiple results. Otherwise you need to add breaks.

Comment: without loop, could u plz tell me how can i do that??

Comment: Your code gives an entirely different result for me, starts with error due to `dict` then gives many empty dict prints and only a few with a link. Can't help you further without more effort on your side sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you, check the code below.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('http://www.freejobalert.com/'
'upsc-recruitment/16960/#Engg-Services2019')
c = page.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
row = soup.find_all('tr')
dict = {}
for i in row:
    for title in i.find_all('span', attrs={
        'style':'color: #008000;'}):
        dict['Title'] = title.text
    for link in i.find_all('a', href=True):
        dict['Link'] = link['href']
        print(dict)
```

Comment: Hi bro just now i have checked by adding diffent url of same site for make it simpler but that page has only one table. but in the dictionary it is giving me one extraa field.. please have a look into first dictionary of my output .

Comment: i think using this way by adding title we can avoid this issue .. do u have any idea how to use title in it??

    find_all('a',attrs={"title":"UPSC"}, href=True):